# How to delete bracket when returning multiple values

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem is teacher wanted this format `Programlama Temelleri I Dersi Ogrenci No: 0000000000 Ağırlıklı Ortalama: 95 Harf Notu: A`  -- and this is the problem that ı'm trying to solve : `Programlama Temelleri I Dersi Ogrenci No: 210911018 Ağırlıklı Ortalama: (95, 'Harf Notu : A')` you can see the problem easily ı dont want bracket and `'` symbol ---  so can someone help me to solve the problem (about returning multiple values without brackets and ' symbol)

Here is the full codes:

```
def lab_odev_arasinav_final(l, o, ara, f):   
    agirlikli_ortalama = (l * (20/100)) + (o * (15/100)) + (ara * (25/100)) + (f * (40/100)) 
    if agirlikli_ortalama >=90 :
        return (agirlikli_ortalama) , "Harf Notu : A"
    elif agirlikli_ortalama >=75 :
        return "Harf Notu: B"
    elif agirlikli_ortalama >=60 : 
        return "Harf Notu : C"
    elif agirlikli_ortalama >=45 : 
        return "Harf Notu : D" 
    else :
        return "Harf Notu : F"  

ortalama = lab_odev_arasinav_final(95 , 95 , 80, 95)      
print("Programlama Temelleri I Dersi" , "Ogrenci No: 210911018" , "Ağırlıklı Ortalama:", ortalama,)
```

Comment: your_str  = your_str.replace('(','').replace(')','').replace("'", '')

Comment: Add a star before printing it..`print("Programlama Temelleri I Dersi" , "Ogrenci No: 210911018" , "Ağırlıklı Ortalama:", *ortalama,)`

Comment: Thank you sir it worked and also f" worked  :) @SamDaniel

Answer (score 0):

On this line `return (agirlikli_ortalama) , "Harf Notu : A"`, you are returning two distinct values - Python creates a "tuple" object with it, and, when printed, a tup[le will display the surrounding brackets, and the "repr" of inner strings, meaning it shows the `'` delimitators.

The fix is simple instead of separating the return values by a comma, use a formatted string (strings prefixed with `f˜`) - that will return a single string which is printed with no brackets by default.

So, just replace that line for: `return f"{agirlikli_ortalama} "Harf Notu : A"`

Comment: extra " before Harf

Comment: Thank you sir it worked :)